# kernel update broke network, rollback fixed, how to report

Tags: wireless, kernel, ethernet

I look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs and it looks like I can gather information for reporting by running `ubuntu-bug`, then it opens Apport to send the report.  The problem is that I have no network on kernel `4.18.0-15-generic`, if I revert to `4.18.0-13-generic` everything is fine.  So if I run it on the broken kernel, how can I send from the non-broken one, does it save a file somewhere that I could send?  Would it even detect such an issue?

Additional info from `lspci`,

```
3a:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fb (rev 10)
```

EDIT: finding the crash report helped, just a corrupt file on install,

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Comment: If a program crashes (esp. important ones) and they generate a crash.dump, you should find it in /var/crash/.  These can be reported using `ubuntu-bug`  (`ubuntu_bug /var/crash/_path_bin_progr.1000.crash`).  If you have the crash on the newer kernel, then I'd hope you could boot into your working kernel, and submit the apport report there by providing the path for the /var/crash/_report.crash.   This won't work if the crash was so fast that no kernel dumps were created, but I'd look anyway.