# Realtek driver dns problem

Tags: networking, drivers, dns, realtek

Somthing happened with the latest update for 18.04.  I have a desktop machine on the network with the same dns servers that work fine, but my laptop on the same network, same dns entries give error `server IP address could not be found. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`  Also, I can switch to using my phone wifi hotspot, the phone reaches all sites, but laptop does not.  I suspect a driver issue, but I am 10 hours into trial and error and would really appreciate any help.

I have tried the `r8168-dkms` driver.  I have played with `resolved.conf`, `NetworkManager.conf` and I keep hitting dead ends.

```
> lspci
3a:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
3b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fb (rev 10)
```

```
> nmcli device show wlp59s0 | grep IP4.DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             209.18.47.61
IP4.DNS[2]:                             209.18.47.63
```

EDIT:

```
> ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 13  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf

> ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=27.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=26.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=24.3 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 24.373/26.153/27.929/1.451 ms
```

EDIT 2, updated link `ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf`

```
> ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=33.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=85.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=54 time=22.5 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 22.536/47.117/85.325/27.384 ms

> ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
PING www.ubuntu.com (91.189.89.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from www-ubuntu-com.nuno.canonical.com (91.189.89.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=51 time=139 ms
64 bytes from www-ubuntu-com.nuno.canonical.com (91.189.89.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=51 time=164 ms
64 bytes from www-ubuntu-com.nuno.canonical.com (91.189.89.110): icmp_seq=3 ttl=51 time=191 ms

--- www.ubuntu.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 139.502/165.177/191.481/21.224 ms
```

note: I resolved [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117257/kernel-update-broke-network-rollback-fixed-how-to-report) issue, but I had the same dns issue when I booted to the `.13` kernel

Comment: Please edit your question to show the resut of: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` and also: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ran:

```
 ls -al /etc/resolv.conf
```

Your result was:

```
wxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jan 13  2018 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

In your case, resolv.conf is not pointing to systemd as expected. Therefore, I suggest that you remove and recreate the link:

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Reboot and show us:

```
ping -c3 8.8.8.8
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

**NOTE**: From my machine, your DNS nameservers,  209.18.47.61 and                        209.18.47.63 are not pingable and I wonder if the numbers are valid.

Comment: I can ping the dns servers, and I seem to reach major sites, such as this one, but many sites are unreachable from this machine, but other machines on the network using same dns entries have no issues.  I can randomly reach some sites, fosstodon.org for example, sometimes yes, sometimes no, way too many sites when searching to resolve this issue are unreachable on this machine only.

Comment: After link update and reboot it seems to be reaching all sites now, thanks.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Glad it's working.